# How can I set absolute path in logging.ini Python

Tags: python, logging

My project file structure looks like:

```
project
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt    
│   main.py
|
└───log
│   │   clear_log.py
│   │   file.log
```

I wrote the fileHandler inside `logging.ini`

```
[handler_fileHandler\]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=("log/file.log",)
```

I call

```py
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig("logging.ini", disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("log something.")
```

in both `main.py` and `clear_log.py`, however, the `args` inside `handler_fileHandler` is set to be "log/file.log", the function above work inside `main.py`, didn't work inside `clear_log.py`, error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

How can I solve it? Can I set an absolute path inside `logging.ini` `args`, or any other better solution for it?